# Copying elements of multiple source tuples to the destination tuple

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I'm trying to assign values of all elements from multiple source tuples to elements of one destination tuple as follows:

```
#include <tuple>

template<std::size_t from_element, typename dstT, typename srcTs, std::size_t... Is>
void assign_elms(dstT& dst, const srcTs& src, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    ((std::get<from_element + Is>(dst) = std::get<Is>(src)), ...);
}

template<std::size_t from_element, typename dstT, typename srcT>
void assign_impl(dstT& dst, const srcT& src) {
    assign_elms<from_element>(dst, src, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<srcT>>());
}

template<typename dstT, typename... srsTs>
void assign(dstT& dst, const srsTs&... srcs) {
    (assign_impl<???>(dst, srcs), ...); // ???
}

template<typename... Ts>
using tuple_concat_t = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<Ts>()...));

int main() {

    std::tuple t1{ 1, 2.2f, 3.33 };
    std::tuple t2{ 4, 5.5f };
    std::tuple t3{ 6 };

    tuple_concat_t<decltype(t1), decltype(t2), decltype(t3)> tr;
    assign(tr, t1, t2, t3); // required (1, 2.2f, 3.33, 4, 5.5f, 6)
}
```

I want to create a destination tuple in advance and then assign elements many times.
But I don't know what to substitute instead of '???'.
Please help me.

I solved this problem using recursion, but I want to do it without recursion.

Creating a new tuple doesn't suit me:

```
template <typename... Ts>
auto tuple_concat(const Ts&... srcs) { return std::tuple_cat(srcs...); }
```

Comment: So basically you want to reimplement [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat)?

Comment: note that "how to fix this code?" and "how to concatenate tuples?" is actually two different questions, because the latter can be done much simpler. Perhaps clarify whether this is an exercise on tuples and templates, or just an attempt to get it done

Comment: `tr = std__tuple_cat(t1, t2, t3);`?

Comment: Yes, this is an exercise on tuples. More precisely, an exercise on templates.

Comment: I want to create a tuple in advance and then assign elements many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might create an array of offsets and iterate over it:

```
template<typename dstT, typename... srsTs>
void assign(dstT& dst, const srsTs&... srcs) {
    constexpr std::array offsets = [](){
        std::array<std::size_t, 1 + sizeof...(srcs)> res{{0, std::tuple_size_v<srsTs>...}};
        std::partial_sum(res.begin(), res.end(), res.begin());

        return res;
    }();
    [&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
        (assign_impl<offsets[Is]>(dst, srcs), ...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(srsTs)>());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eKGnzbT9s).

Comment: This is really a very visual linear solution. This way I can apply not only assignment, but also addition, subtraction and many other operations to the destination tuple. Thank you.